# Porting PL/pgSQL stored procedures?

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, stored-procedures, pljava

We have some PL/pgSQL stored procedures in our DB (PostgreSQL 9.x).

These are strictly sequential, and under some circumstances, can be very slow.

We are thinking on porting these to PL/Java, PL/Python or something like these, and exploit the multithreading abilities of these languages.

The main question is: how "effectively" these language supports are implemented? For example, I'm thinking on the Virtual Machines that run Java code: when calling my PL/Java code, each time it summons a new VM for it, or does PL/Java keeps some kind of pool of VMs, and associate one of them for the actual call?

Comment: What is slow in the procedure? That's what you want to fix, porting a problem to a different language won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pl/Java runs in a jvm embedded in the postgres backend process.  See: [PL/Java wiki](http://wiki.tada.se/index.php?title=Technoloy_in_Brief)

I'd suggest that you don't just translate everything to java without first looking at pure SQL solutions.   In many cases SQL's ability to work on a large number of records in bulk will outweigh any benefit of dealing with records individually but leading to more SQL calls.

The multi-threading capability of Java doesn't give benefits if the task is inherently sequential.

Comment: Thanks guys, we are putting together the information these weeks before making any decisions. Your comments are really helpful!